# MVC passing object from model through controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't have much experience with programming and I'm new to MVC.

I want to fetch some data from database with entity framework and print it in the view.

This is my model:

```
public class Grad
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Naziv { get; set; }
    public char KoordinataX { get; set; }
    public char KoordinataY { get; set; }
    public int BrojStanovnika { get; set; }
}
public class GradDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Grad> Gradovi { get; set; }
}
```

this is a controller:

```
private GradDBContext db = new GradDBContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<int> gradoviList = new List<int>();
        foreach (sea.Models.Grad g in db.Gradovi)
        {
            gradoviList.Add(g.ID);
        }
        ViewData["Gradovi"] = new SelectList(gradoviList);
        return View();
    }
```

and this is a view:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["Gradovi"] as IEnumerable<int>) ---> error appears here as null reference exception
            {
                <p>item</p>
            }
```

I know that I have to parse data but don't have idea what did I do wrong

Comment: thank you for your answer. As I sad, I'm new to programming and MVC and still not quite familiar with entity framework and that kind of stuff. This is the first time I'm trying to print something from the database. Yes, just trying to display a list of IDs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ViewData` item with the key `"Gradovi"` is typeof `SelectList`, so it would need to be

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["Gradovi"] as SelectList)
{
    <p>@item.Value</p> // or @item.Text
```

However there is no point generating `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (which is what `SelectList` is) when you do not need it, and you should be passing your model to the view. Your code in the controller should be

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<int> model = db.Gradovi.Select(x => x.ID);
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<int>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <p>@item</p>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can work like you have it, but I am going to modify it a bit and give you some pointers. I am supplying an answer based on what I see in your post, not what I think you want to achieve at a later stage. There are many ways to accomplish a goal, I will select the simplest way that I will normally use:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     // You will have a repository layer for this part
     GradDBContext db = new GradDBContext();

     // Get a list of your items
     List<Grad> gradovis = db.Gradovi.ToList();

     // I never work with view data, I just pass my view model to the view
     // This way you now have more data to display on the screen (if you need more)
     return View(gradovis);
}
```

And then your view could look like this:

```
@model List<Project.Model.Grad>

@foreach (var grad in Model)
{
     <p>@grad.ID</p>
}
```